Proving a lesser form of Lagrange's Theorem
Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with $n$ elements, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ with $m$ elements. Show $m$ divides $n$. Here is my work on this.
First, we use the facts that any two cosets $I+a$ and $I+b$ of $I$ are either equal or disjoint, and that they have the same number of elements since $f: I+a \rightarrow I+b$ given by $f(x) = x-a+b$ is a bijection.
Now let $R = \{r_1,r_2...r_n\}$, and assume without loss of generality that $I = \{r_1,r_2...r_m\} \subseteq R$. If $m=n$, we are done. So let $m < n$, and consider the coset $I + r_{m+1}$. This is a set of $m$ elements in $R$ that is disjoint from $I$ (or they could be equal, in which case we can ignore it). Repeating this process with $r_{m+2},r_{m+3}...r_n$ yields a total of $q$ sets of $m$ elements in $R$, all disjoint from one another, where $q$ is at most $n-(m+1)$.
Is this reasoning correct? And how do I show that these sets completely partition $R$, in which case we can conclude that $mq=n$? Meaning, given $r \in R$, how can I claim that $r \in I+a$ for some $a \in \{0,r_{m+1}...r_n\}$? I can sense an equivalence relation lurking here, but I just can't see it.
Also, I have not gotten to group theory yet. This is just a smaller result that my textbook will use to set up Lagrange's Theorem later on.

The different cosets form a partition of $R$, because $x\in R$ always belongs to the coset $x+I$. So $R$ is the disjoint union of the distinct cosets, which all have size $m$. So $|R|$ is equal to $m$ times the number of cosets.

When you get to Group Theory, you will learn that a ring is a group, and an ideal is a subgroup, so Lagrange applies.
